# PYTHON Dataframe: how to make a new dataframe with the difference of values between today and yesterday?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi all: this is maybe a simple task but I cannot understand how to write it.
I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati- 
json/dpc-covid19-ita-province.json',
convert_dates =['data']) 
df.index = df['data']
df.index = df.index.normalize()
df = df[df["sigla_provincia"] == 'VR']
df['totale_casi'] = df['totale_casi'] + 1
ts = df[['totale_casi']].dropna()
sts = ts.totale_casi
```

I understand that if I write "df['totale_casi'] = df['totale_casi'] + 1" I simply add 1 to every value of the column 'totale_casi' and this is simple.

But if you look at the url [GITHUBLINK](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-json/dpc-covid19-ita-province.json) you may see that for every province of Italy I have for every day the TOTAL number of covid cases (the target province is Verona btw) which is good but I want to build a dataframe that contains for every day the difference between 'totale_casi'of today and 'totale_casi' of yesterday, something like this (pseudocode)

```
df['totale_casi'] = df['totale_casi'][today] - df['totale_casi'][yesterday]
```

for each day of the json.
How to solve the task?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['totale_casi'] = df['totale_casi'].diff(periods=1)
```

Comment: This solved the problem. Thank you. Unfortunately I cannot add +1 because I am a new user but many thanks again because now the problem is solved :)

Comment: @Fllecha: You can accept the answer by clicking the checkbox under the voting buttons.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, the dataset looks like it is already temporally ordered.
So I think the simplest solution is:

```
df['totale_casi'] = df['totale_casi'].diff()
```

I hope I have helped you!

Comment: Thanks. Needed (periods=1) to work, but thank you ;)